# Calculating difference between dates based on grouping one or more columns

Tags: r, group-by, date-difference

A sample of my dataset is as below:

```
| id |       Date | Buyer    |
|:--:|-----------:|----------|
|  9 | 11/29/2018 | Jenny    |
|  9 | 11/29/2018 | Jenny    |
|  9 | 11/29/2018 | Jenny    |
| 4  | 5/30/2018  | Chang    |
| 4  | 7/4/2018   | Chang    |
| 4  | 8/17/2018  | Chang    |
| 5  | 5/25/2018  | Chunfei  |
| 5  | 2/13/2019  | Chunfei  |
| 5  | 2/16/2019  | Chunfei  |
| 5  | 2/16/2019  | Chunfei  |
| 5  | 2/23/2019  | Chunfei  |
| 5  | 2/25/2019  | Chunfei  |
| 8  | 2/28/2019  | Chunfei  |
| 8  | 2/28/2019  | Chunfei  |
```

I have two sets of questions with this dataset:

1. I need to calculate the difference between dates but this difference will be calculated based on grouping 'Buyer' and 'id', which means, the date difference for the Buyer 'Jenny' and Id '9' will be one group, Buyer 'Chang' with Id '4' will be another group and Buyer 'Chunfei' with Id '5' will be another group and 'Chunfei' with Id '8' will be another group. So, the output will be:

```
| id |       Date | Buyer_id | Diff |
|:--:|-----------:|----------|------|
|  9 | 11/29/2018 | Jenny    | NA   |
|  9 | 11/29/2018 | Jenny    | 0    |
|  9 | 11/29/2018 | Jenny    | 0    |
| 4  | 5/30/2018  | Chang    | NA   |
| 4  | 7/4/2018   | Chang    | 35   |
| 4  | 8/17/2018  | Chang    | 44   |
| 5  | 5/25/2018  | Chunfei  | NA   |
| 5  | 2/13/2019  | Chunfei  | 264  |
| 5  | 2/16/2019  | Chunfei  | 3    |
| 5  | 2/16/2019  | Chunfei  | 0    |
| 5  | 2/23/2019  | Chunfei  | 7    |
| 5  | 2/25/2019  | Chunfei  | 2    |
| 8  | 2/28/2019  | Chunfei  | NA   |
| 8  | 2/28/2019  | Chunfei  | 0    |
```

The issue is that I'm not understanding why the group_by isn't working. The following code subtracts the consecutive rows rather than grouping them for same buyer and id and then subtracting.

```
df=data.frame(id=c("9","9","9","4","4","4","5","5","5","5","5","5","8","8"), 
              Date=c("11/29/2018","11/29/2018","11/29/2018","5/30/2018","7/4/2018", 
                      "8/17/2018","5/25/2018","2/13/2019","2/16/2019","2/16/2019","2/23/2019",
                      "2/25/2019","2/28/2019","2/28/2019"),Buyer=c("Jenny","Jenny","Jenny",
                      "Chang","Chang","Chang","Chunfei","Chunfei","Chunfei","Chunfei","Chunfei",
                      "Chunfei","Chunfei","Chunfei"))
df$id=as.numeric(as.character(df$id))
df$Date=as.Date(df$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")
df$Buyer=as.character(df$Buyer)

df1=df %>% group_by(Buyer,id) %>%
  mutate(diff=as.numeric(difftime(Date,lag(Date),units='days')))
```

2. After calculating the date difference, I need to filter those records whose differences between dates are 5 days. In the above example, the date difference between "5/25/2018", "2/13/2019","2/16/2019","2/16/2019","2/23/2019","2/25/2019" will be NA,264,3,0,7,2. However, if I provide a filter for n<6, I would miss on the dates "2/13/2019" and "2/23/2019". These dates will be important to retain in the final output, because even though the difference between dates "2/13/2019" and "5/25/2018" is 264, the difference between "2/16/2019" and "2/13/2019" is 3. Similarly, even though the difference between "2/16/2019" and "2/23/2019" is 7, the difference between "2/23/2019" and "2/25/2019" is 2. So,I need to retain these dates. How can this be achieved?

We can mask the column 'diff' in the final output and it should look like below:

```
| id |    Date    | Buyer_id |
|----|:----------:|---------:|
| 9  | 11/29/2018 |    Jenny |
| 9  | 11/29/2018 |    Jenny |
| 9  | 11/29/2018 |    Jenny |
| 5  | 2/13/2019  | Chunfei  |
| 5  | 2/16/2019  | Chunfei  |
| 5  | 2/16/2019  | Chunfei  |
| 5  | 2/23/2019  | Chunfei  |
| 5  | 2/25/2019  | Chunfei  |
| 8  | 2/28/2019  | Chunfei  |
| 8  | 2/28/2019  | Chunfei  |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `diff` to subtract `Date` and select groups where there is at-least one value which is less than equal to 5 days.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id, Buyer) %>%
  filter(any(diff(Date) <= 5))

#      id Date       Buyer  
#   <dbl> <date>     <chr>  
# 1     9 2018-11-29 Jenny  
# 2     9 2018-11-29 Jenny  
# 3     9 2018-11-29 Jenny  
# 4     5 2018-05-25 Chunfei
# 5     5 2019-02-13 Chunfei
# 6     5 2019-02-16 Chunfei
# 7     5 2019-02-16 Chunfei
# 8     5 2019-02-23 Chunfei
# 9     5 2019-02-25 Chunfei
#10     8 2019-02-28 Chunfei
#11     8 2019-02-28 Chunfei
```

---

After re-reading the question I think you might not be looking to `filter` entire groups but only those rows which have difference of 5 days. We can get indices which have `diff` value of less than 5 and select it's previous index as well.

```
df %>%
  group_by(id, Buyer) %>%
  mutate(diff = c(NA, diff(Date))) %>%
  slice({i1 <- which(diff <= 5); unique(c(i1, i1-1))}) %>%
  select(-diff)

#      id Date       Buyer  
#   <dbl> <date>     <chr>  
# 1     5 2019-02-16 Chunfei
# 2     5 2019-02-16 Chunfei
# 3     5 2019-02-25 Chunfei
# 4     5 2019-02-13 Chunfei
# 5     5 2019-02-23 Chunfei
# 6     8 2019-02-28 Chunfei
# 7     8 2019-02-28 Chunfei
# 8     9 2018-11-29 Jenny  
# 9     9 2018-11-29 Jenny  
#10     9 2018-11-29 Jenny
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(9, 9, 9, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 8, 
8), Date = structure(c(17864, 17864, 17864, 17681, 17716, 17760, 
17676, 17940, 17943, 17943, 17950, 17952, 17955, 17955), class = "Date"), 
Buyer = c("Jenny", "Jenny", "Jenny", "Chang", "Chang", "Chang", 
"Chunfei", "Chunfei", "Chunfei", "Chunfei", "Chunfei", "Chunfei", 
"Chunfei", "Chunfei")), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: The difference is still not getting calculated based on groups. I'm missing out quite a few records because of that in my original dataset.

Comment: Also, when we execute the line, ``` df1=df %>%  group_by(id,Buyer) %>%   mutate(diff = c(NA, diff(Date))) %>% slice({i1 <- which(diff <= 5)})``` it is supposed to filter out everything except the records having diff<=5, but in the output we see records which has diff of -183 and -84 as well. Why is it so?

Comment: @hk2 This seem to work on the shared data. Can you share a dataset where the above method fails so that it is easier to debug and provide a solution?

Comment: The above dataset is similar to my original dataset. My query is that for the above given dataset when I run only this set of line  ``` df1=df %>% group_by(id,Buyer) %>% mutate(diff = c(NA, diff(Date))) %>% slice({i1 <- which(diff <= 5)})```, why does it bring out the records that have values -183 and -84 in the "diff" column, even though it is supposed to filter out everything else and retain the records having diff<=5? Could you please explain me this?

Comment: @hk2 For me it filters out only those records where `diff <=5`. Can you check once again? `df %>%
  group_by(id, Buyer) %>%
  mutate(diff = c(NA, diff(Date))) %>%
  slice(which(diff <= 5))
`

Comment: I checked it again by reducing the size of my dataset. It worked. Thanks a lot!